# Difference between get_called_class() and static::class

Tags: php, class, static

What is the difference between calling `get_called_class()` and `static::class` inside a static class method?

For example:

```
class Base
{
    public static function foo()
    {
        return static::class;
    }

    public static function bar()
    {
        return get_called_class();
    }
}

class Child extends Base {}

echo Base::foo();  // prints 'Base'
echo Base::bar();  // prints 'Base'
echo Child::foo(); // prints 'Child'
echo Child::bar(); // prints 'Child'
```

It appears to work the same in both cases but there may be some nuances I should be aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static::class` [was "only" added in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php), but other than that they should work identically.

From a quick test, `static::class` appears to be slightly faster. Using the code from the question:

```
profile("Parent, static::class", function () { Base::foo();});
profile("Parent, get_called_class", function () { Base::bar();});
profile("Child, static::class", function () { Child::foo();});
profile("Child, get_called_class", function () { Child::bar();});
```

> Parent, static::class took 0.0467 seconds
>
> Parent, get_called_class took 0.0559 seconds
>
> Child, static::class took 0.0468 seconds
>
> Child, get_called_class took 0.0554 seconds

But you've got to be doing well into six-figures worth of iterations to notice. See https://3v4l.org/qaXln (3v4l definitely isn't the best tool for benchmarking, but there's enough of a pattern)

Comment: So given that `static::class` is a little bit faster and works the same as `get_called_class`, there's not reason to use the latter in modern applications?

Comment: @KubaSzymanowski Yep, exactly. It's not enough of an improvement to go back and change old code, but new code might as well use the slightly faster version. It's also a bit nicer, in my opinion at least.